# how to increase number animation using styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to implement an animation that increases the number using a styled component.

```
const Info = styled.div`
  margin-left: 35rem;
  margin-top: -15rem;
  p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: 500;
    strong {
      font-weight: 600;
      @property --num {
        syntax: '<integer>';
        initial-value: 0;
        inherits: false;
      }
    }
  }
  animation: ${ImgFade} 0.7s linear;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
`
```

```
      <Info>
        <p>
          <strong>350</strong>User
        </p>
      </Info>
```

I'm using @property(css property), it seems not work..